# How can I make a superclass of a template class abstract?

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, virtual

I have declared the following classes in a header file (Environment.h) and I would like to make the superclass FieldAccessor abstract:

```
#include <jni.h>

class FieldAccessor {

    public:
        FieldAccessor(
            JNIEnv* env
        ) {
            this->jNIEnv = env;
        }

        virtual jobject getValue(jobject, jobject) = 0;

    protected:
        JNIEnv* jNIEnv;
};

template<typename Type>
class PrimitiveFieldAccessor : public FieldAccessor {
    public :
        PrimitiveFieldAccessor (
            JNIEnv* env, const char name[], const char ctorSig[],
            Type (JNIEnv::*getFieldValueFunction) (jobject, jfieldID)
        );

        jobject getValue(jobject, jobject);

    private:
        jclass type;
        jmethodID constructorId;
        Type (JNIEnv::*getFieldValueFunction) (jobject, jfieldID);
};
```

But I obtain the following compilation error:

```sh
F:/Shared/Workspaces/Projects/JNI/src/DriverFunctionSupplierNative.cpp: In instantiation of '_jobject* PrimitiveFieldAccessor<Type>::getValue(jobject, jobject) [with Type = long int; jobject = _jobject*]':
F:/Shared/Workspaces/Projects/JNI/src/Environment.h:73:11:   required from here
F:/Shared/Workspaces/Projects/JNI/src/DriverFunctionSupplierNative.cpp:80:2: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((PrimitiveFieldAccessor<long int>*)this)->PrimitiveFieldAccessor<long int>::getFieldValueFunction (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((PrimitiveFieldAccessor<long int>*)this)->PrimitiveFieldAccessor<long int>::getFieldValueFunction) (...)'
```

This is a piece of the implementation file (*DriverFunctionSupplierNative.cpp)*:

```
template<typename Type>
PrimitiveFieldAccessor<Type>::PrimitiveFieldAccessor (
    JNIEnv* env,
    const char name[],
    const char ctorSig[],
    Type (JNIEnv::*getFieldValueFunction) (jobject, jfieldID)
) : FieldAccessor(env) {
    this->jNIEnv = env;
    this->type = (jclass)jNIEnv->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass(name));
    this->constructorId = jNIEnv->GetMethodID(this->type, "<init>", ctorSig);
    this->getFieldValueFunction = getFieldValueFunction;
}

template<typename Type>
jobject PrimitiveFieldAccessor<Type>::getValue(jobject target, jobject field) {
    jfieldID fieldId = jNIEnv->FromReflectedField(field);
    return jNIEnv->NewObject(
        this->type,
        this->constructorId,
        this->getFieldValueFunction(target, fieldId)
    );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with half a dozen fields and methods? How about you try it with just one first. Point is, creating a [mcve] helps understanding the problem, which is also why it is required. As a relatively new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: the error is the same for all 4 methods declared virtual: if I remove the virtual keyword and the expression '= 0' at the end of the methods I have no compilation errors, but ok i modify it

Comment: I reduced the code. And the error is probably in the method `jobject PrimitiveFieldAccessor<Type>::getValue(jobject target, jobject field)`
Exactly in this line of code: `this->getFieldValueFunction(target, fieldId)` But I haven't understand which is the correct code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error%3A+must+use+%27.*%27+or+%27-%3E*%27+to+call+pointer-to-member+function -- just search for the error. BTW: It's still not a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried copy'n'pasting it into a file in order to reproduce the issue? You'd probably have found that it's not that easy, because it isn't complete.  And there's still a probably unnecessary dependency on JNI, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compilation error is quite descriptive of the problem. Take the time to read them and learn what they mean:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '...', e.g. ...
```

Now look at how you try to call the function:

```
this->callTypeMethodFunction(
    ...
)
```

The syntax would be something like this:

```
(jNIEnv->*callTypeMethodFunction)(value, this->callTypeMethodId);
```

The same thing applies for the other pointer to the member function calls:

```
return jNIEnv->NewObject(
    this->type,
    this->constructorId,
    (jNIEnv->*getFieldValueFunction)(target, fieldId)
);
```

---

Now why does the compilation error only happen when you have the virtual method? This is because of how template instantiation works. You didn't post how the class will be instantiated, but looking at the symptoms is that the virtual function get instantiated early to build the vtable, but other methods (non-virtual) will only be instantiated on usage.